# What's wrong with this C program using pointer function

Tags: c

When i assign a variable for the pointer function, the program crashes when i run it, but if i print it right away it doesnt (printf("%d",*Largest(parr,10));)

This outputs the address of the largest element in the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *Largest(int*,int);

int main (void)
{
    int arr[10] = {33,7,1,3,8,5,2,10,39,22},*parr,z;

    parr=arr;
    z = *(Largest(parr,10));
    printf ("%d",z);
}

int *Largest (int *array, int size)
{
    int i,*high;

    *high = 0;

    for (i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        if (array[i] < array[i+1]) *high = i+1;
        else *high = i;

    return high;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using your pointer `int *high` incorrectly: you should not be dereferencing (i.e. applying the `*` operator to it) it in your `Largest` function at all. Instead, you should be making "straight" assignments to it.

First, you should assign the pointer to the initial element of `array` to it on initialization:

```
int *high = array; // That's the same as &array[0]
```

Then, you should start your loop at index 1, and assign `high`, not `*high`:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < size ; i++) {
    if (array[i] > *high) {
        high = &array[i];
    }
}
```